# Download a Special git Tag from the Website?

Tags: github

how can I download a special tag from the git website? Especially I want to download from contao core repo tag 2.10.4

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you want to download a special tag of `Contao/core` from github, just append `/tags` to the repo URL address: `https://github.com/contao/core/tags`.  github prepares a list of tags you can download them in `zip` or `tar.gz` format.

But generally, you can `clone` the whole project, and get access to a special tag, by using:

```
git clone https://github.com/contao/core.git
git checkout <tag_name>
```